# ASP.net JavaScript MS Outlook

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript that will open MS Outlook and use the Mailto from a textbox. I would like to check if the textbox is empty show alert "No Email Address Found" else continue to open MS Outlook. How do I add this to my javascript?

```
function TriggerOutlook() {
            var to = document.getElementById("txtEmailAddress").value;
            window.location.href = "mailto:" + to;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if "to" is empty like this:

```
function TriggerOutlook() {
    var to = document.getElementById("txtEmailAddress").value;
    if(to=='') {
        alert("Invalid email address");
        return;
    }
    window.location.href = "mailto:" + to;
}
```